# How to stub query helper method Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, sinon

I'm using Sinon to test my Express/Typescript application. In Mongoose I have models with query helper methods to make query chains.

I have this schema

```
export const articuloSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String, default: v4 },
    numeroInventario: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    descripcion: { type: String, trim: true },
}, {
    versionKey: false,
    query: {
        paginate(page: number, limit: number) {
            return this.skip(page - 1).limit(limit);
        }
    }
});

export type ArticuloType = InferSchemaType<typeof articuloSchema>;

export const Articulo = mongoose.model('Articulo', articuloSchema);
```

and I want to fake my query helper method with Sinon like this

```
const getMultipleArticulos (): ArticuloType[] => {
    const arr:ArticuloType = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr.push({
            numeroInventario: i,
            descripcion: 'string'
        })
    }
    return arr;
}
it('Should return a list of items that belong to a user', function (done) {
    const paginateFake = sinon.fake.resolves(getMultipleArticulos());
    sinon.replace(Articulo, 'paginate', paginateFake);
    chai.request(app)
        .get(`/api/v1/users/${userId}/articulos`)
        .end((err, res) => {
            expect(err).to.be.null;
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            // more expects
            done();
        });
});
```

The problem is that I cannot stub those methods, it says that it can't stub non existent property of 'paginate' (which is the query helper method I added to my model).

Comment: What are `Articulo` and `getMultipleArticulos()`? Show the minimal, complete code